# Joomla2.5.14 Server Side Validation for Login Page

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I am using Joomla2.5.14 and I want to add some more server side validation like:

a) Please enter your email address. (Outline email address box in red). 
b) Your email address is not registered with Us. (Outline email address box in red). 
c) Your email address is invalid. (For invalid email address which is different from registered email address - Outline email address box in red). 
d) Please enter your password. (Outline password box in red). 
e) Your password is incorrect. (Outline password box in red).

in Joomla login page.

For my project I have added "awoelogin" to login with email address.

Can somebody guide me where to apply changes in Joomla files. I want to show error like this style (http://docs.joomla.org/Display_error_messages_and_notices).

Currently I am getting only one error. (Check my attachment)

Thanks

[image: My Login Page]

Answer (score 0):

Insted of changing Joomla files, can't you try using a component like [Chrono Forms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508)?

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion but I have already tried with formcheck.js. Your suggested component is using formcheck.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this in components/com_users/controllers/user.php in method

```
public function login()
{
  if( /*Some Statement*/ )
  {
    $this->setRedirect($link, 'Some Error Text', 'error');
    return;
  }

  /* Here Goes Joomla Code Wich Makes Login */

}
```